# I'm getting an error when I try to run this code - unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
import matplotlib as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import seaborn as sns

df.head()
Out[46]: 
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass    ...        Fare Cabin  Embarked
0            1         0       3    ...      7.2500   NaN         S
1            2         1       1    ...     71.2833   C85         C
2            3         1       3    ...      7.9250   NaN         S
3            4         1       1    ...     53.1000  C123         S
4            5         0       3    ...      8.0500   NaN         S

[5 rows x 12 columns]
```

---

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\dframe.csv')

sns.factorplot('Sex', data = df)
```

### Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-703be846d61b>", line 1, in <module>
    sns.factorplot('Sex', data = df)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 3530, in factorplot
    g.map_dataframe(plot_func, x, y, hue, **plot_kws)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 809, in map_dataframe
    self._facet_plot(func, ax, args, kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py", line 827, in _facet_plot
    func(*plot_args, **plot_kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 3143, in pointplot
    orient, color, palette, errwidth, capsize)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 1669, in __init__
    self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py", line 1482, in estimate_statistic
    statistic.append(estimator(stat_data))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2957, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 82, in _mean
    ret = ret / rcount

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

The dataset I am using is a csv file 'train.csv':

Comment: link for the dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/c/3136/download/train.csv

Comment: can you show us the output of df.head()

Comment: @tobsecret df.head()
Out[46]: 
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass    ...        Fare Cabin  Embarked
0            1         0       3    ...      7.2500   NaN         S
1            2         1       1    ...     71.2833   C85         C
2            3         1       3    ...      7.9250   NaN         S
3            4         1       1    ...     53.1000  C123         S
4            5         0       3    ...      8.0500   NaN         S

[5 rows x 12 columns]

Comment: @DevenBothra Can you put it, **formatted**, in the question. Not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a factorplot but you are just supplying it only with an x-value (`Sex`), so it cannot figure out what to plot for you. The factorplot is meant to be used for creating a `FacetGrid` of plots according to some categorical variables.
What you are looking for may be the `sns.countplot`, see the examples [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html?highlight=countplot#seaborn.countplot).

```
sns.countplot('Sex', data = df)
```

Alternatively if you are just looking to examine all the relationships between the different numerical variables, you can use `sns.pairplot`

```
sns.pairplot(df)
```